# How to implement generic function for adding both numeric and string value in swift but without add the extension for each data type?

Tags: swift, generics, protocols, extension-methods, addition

I am trying to add two values with different-2 data types using a generic function in swift, I tried using extensions, to declare conformance to the particular protocols for the types that I want. It's working fine code snippet is below but I want some optimized way where I don't want to add the extension for each data type like below :

```
protocol Addable {
       static func +(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
  }
```

Now, using extensions, declare conformance to Addable for the all types:

```
 extension String: Addable {}
 extension Int: Addable {}
 extension Double: Addable {}
 .
 .
 .  
 extension Float: Addable {}
```

And define your add function as:

```
 func addition<T: Addable>(first: T, second: T) -> T {
      return first + second
 }
```

Can anyone suggest an optimized solution, that doesn't require the extension for each data type?

Comment: Considering that in the real code you probably does not just do simple addition, how about letting the caller pass in the `+` operator? The call would look like `addition(first: foo, second: bar, operation: +)`. This way you do not have to define any protocols or extensions.